# Move second row to first row and after that all record follow same order in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

I have a table with this structure , I want to show record basis on weeks name i.e. monday on first position, tuesday on second ...so on sunday on last position So I need to change monday to first and sunday will last.

[image: The data]

```
1   Sunday  00:30:00.000    19:30:00.000
2   Monday  01:30:00.000    17:01:00.000
3   Tuesday 23:00:00.000    00:30:00.000
4   Wednesday   01:00:00.000    15:54:00.000
5   Thursday    00:00:00.000    00:00:00.000
6   Friday  00:00:00.000    22:00:00.000
7   Saturday    00:00:00.000    21:30:00.000
```

Comment: Can you attach your current SQL query? How do you get Weekday from database - what type of field is it that you use to get weekday?

Comment: I don't follow your data.  Note that there is no real internal order to your table.  If you want to see the data in a certain order, then you need the right `ORDER BY` clause in your select query.

Comment: I have a table structure like this, now i need to sort data on Day name wise i.e. Monday on first position  , Tuesday on second and so on...

Comment: field name   Id ,Name , startdate and enddate

Comment: Table name - Record

Comment: Please, write your current query in the form select  ...

Comment: select Id, Name , StartDate, Enddate from record Order by Id

Answer (score 1):

Use the below SQL:

```
 Select dayname(date_column), date_column from table_name order by weekday(date_column);
```

You have to just use the `Order by weekday(date_column)` in your SQL query

**weekday()** function returns below codes for day:

Monday.    0

Tuesday.   1

Wednesday. 2

Thursday. 3

Friday. 4

Saturday.5

Sunday. 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weekday(mydate)` to get the value you need and order by it.

- weekday(mydate) will convert "date" into weekday number (`Monday = 0`)

  select weekday(mydate), mydate, dayname(mydate) from tbl
  order by weekday(mydate);

Example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11711a/9

Answer (score 0):

I believe you won't be able to order it by DaysName where first one is Monday because you can't really form a DateTime by only using DayOfWeek and Time portions of the DateTime.

If this table only holds 7 records (one for each day of week), then you might want to look at rearranging the record id's in the order you want which would then allow you to order them and get expected result.

```
    CREATE TABLE Your_TableName
    (
    DayId int primary key,
    DaysName nvarchar(max)
    )

    INSERT INTO Your_TableName
    VALUES ('1', 'Sunday'),
    ('2', 'Monday'),
    ('3', 'Tuesday'),
    ('4', 'Wednesday'),
    ('5', 'Thursday'),
    ('6', 'Friday'),
    ('7', 'Saturday')

    --Move Sunday to the back to release the first id
    UPDATE Your_TableName
    SET DayId = '8'
    WHERE DayId = '1'

    --Don't technically have to do this, but you can move the rest of the records
    --to also reclaim that ID that was just released in order to have 1-7 Ids
    UPDATE Your_TableName
    SET DayId = DayId - 1

    select * from Your_TableName
    order by dayId
```

Your result will be as follows

```
    DayId   DaysName
    1   Monday
    2   Tuesday
    3   Wednesday
    4   Thursday
    5   Friday
    6   Saturday
    7   Sunday
```